# Not able to update table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am generating a script to update. It is a string. If I take that and execute in Toad, it is updating. But in code, I am not able to do. I am getting "transaction required exception".

Code is:

```
String updateQuery = 
"update asset_dmr_revision_test
    set revision_date_test = '"+str+"'
    where asset_id ="+map.getValue()+" and
        revision_id="+Integer.parseInt(assetRevision.getFileVersion()+"")+"";
entityManager.createNativeQuery(updateQuery).executeUpdate();
entityManager.flush();
```

I am getting below error.

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:46)
    at com.sony.spe.b2b.session.DMRServiceUtility.updateRevisedDate(DMRServiceUtility.java:136)
    at com.sony.spe.b2b.session.DMRServiceUtility.main(DMRServiceUtility.java:64)
```

What is the fix?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error you are getting. Additionally, try starting a Transaction.

Comment: The fix is running it with-in a Transaction.

Comment: what u using u directly updating query??

Comment: but u can do one thing na according to me update is some kinda difficult process but u can select that record and update with new one that will be easy way. i mean save or update.

Answer (score 0):

@Elliot is correct. problem got solved when I run within a transaction.Thank you Elliot